# How to get twitter original profile picture through API call

Tags: twitter

right now we are getting 84*84 profile picture, but we need original twitter profile picture into http n https. Please lemme know how to get dat?

Comment: Hi Satya, please could you show us the code you've written? It's hard for us to help if we can't see what you've already done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the URL to the user's profile image in the `profile_image_url_https` field in the User object.

Note that, in the next version of the Twitter API (Twitter Developer Labs), the field is simply called `profile_image_url` and it will always return an https URL value. Do not use the legacy `profile_image_url` if you are using the v1.1 API.

Once you have the URL, you can add or modify the end of the path to request different sizes. Twitter [supports a number of different values](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/user-profile-images-and-banners): `normal`, `bigger`, `mini`, and `original`. By default, you'll get back the "normal" variant which is probably 48x48px.

For example, my profile image is currently returned as
`https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1230679874039427074/sMPPa2tz_normal.jpg`

You can request "bigger" by changing the URL to include `_bigger` instead of `_normal`, or you can ask for the original size by dropping `_normal` completely. In the case of the example above, that currently returns a 400x400px image.

Comment: (please mark this answer as correct if it resolved your question)